# My RAM is defective, should I reinstall my OS?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory

My stick of RAM is defective, and has been behind numerous errors on my PC in the past few months since I built it. After I confirmed that the RAM was the culprit with MemTest86, I've purchased a new stick.

Should I reinstall my OS and clear my drives? I've read that defective RAM can cause degradation to boot drives and other drives, and possibly causing errors due to an OS installation with said RAM?

Comment: Can you cite references to what you read?  Theoretically, anything is possible, but I've never heard of such associated problems.  I wouldn't prophylactically reinstall the OS, wipe drives, or anything similar if you have no other symptoms of problems after you replace the RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need to reinstall Windows due to faulty RAM.

As long as your files are intact (`chkdsk /f` and `sfc /scannow` should take care of both user and system files), your files are all right!

Most RAM is used internally in programs, and as such there is a very small probability of the corrupt parts of your RAM causing corruption in data that a program writes to disk. Every time you restart, the RAM is cleared; as a result, different programs may be allocated to these same parts of the memory each session.

This is the great part about PCs, that you can replace the RAM without needing to replace or reinstall anything else (unlike tablets and other embedded hardware).

Comment: Yeah, but throwing out the baby with the bath water won't get you anything. The suggested commands should take care of anything functional. If any saved data is corrupted, reinstalling the OS won't fix it.

Comment: @Eridnis: Why do you think it's likely that anything is corrupted?  RAM problems tend to cause immediate operational failures.  If anything is corrupted in the process, it is likely your user files.  There isn't much in the operating system that gets routinely rewritten to disk so it has little exposure to corruption that can't be cleaned up with what's described here.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm saying that it's not, and there are tools to verify this.

Comment: What tools are those?

Comment: @Eridnis The toola stated above.